# cannot connect to network in ubuntu server 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, server, wired

I had recently installed an ubuntu 12.10 server edition and i am new to this.
During the installation I skipped the configure network section, and now i cant connect to any network.
I used the    lshw -C network    and found that both my wired and wireless adapters are disabled.
Someone please help me to get this thing fixed. Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the content of **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** files to get the names assigned to your network devices by **udev**. Usually, those should be **eth0** for wired and **wlan0** for wireless.

Then, put the following content into the **/etc/network/interfaces** file (replace *eth0* and *wlan0* names if needed):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Tha above will work fine if only you have the **DHCP** server in your network. If no, you can assign static IP address according to the following example:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.2
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/268056). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) it should be customized to account for what is different about the questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.