# how to enable internet with ubuntu 10.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 10.04, internet, ethernet

I have installed UBUNTU 10.04 dual with my windows 8.
but the internet is disabled, both the Ethernet and wireless,
I try this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1521228) but when  type this commands

```
sudo apt-get update
```

there are packages that it fails to install

I try to type this command `ifconfig` , and I see just the `lo` interface: there is no eth or wlan ?

Comment: Any specific reason you opt/choose the quite out-dated 10.4 version of ubuntu? A thought: maybe 12.04 would not give you the same troubles?

Comment: I strongly suggest you install 12.04 or 12.10 as 10.04 will be end of life, no longer supported in a few weeks time.  Hardware support is improving all the time.  Let us know if you are still having issues with either 12.04 or 12.10.

Comment: Please provide the results of lspci | grep Ethernet in a terminal in order to see if your Ethernet adapter is being recognized. If you receive no-results then you are experiencing a hardware issue. Thank you.

Comment: ok i will try this ,, but i need to build ANDROID SOURCE on this version is recommended for that

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo,,,, i think it is recognized ::this output ::

hana@hana-laptop:~$ lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)

Answer (score 1):

Check the content of **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** files to get the names assigned to your network devices by **udev**. Usually, those should be **eth0** for wired and **wlan0** for wireless.

Then, put the following content into the **/etc/network/interfaces** file (replace *eth0* and *wlan0* names if needed):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Tha above will work fine if only you have the **DHCP** server in your network. If no, you can assign static IP address according to the following example:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.2
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.0.1
```